# Transformations at goniometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

(a) Make the appropriate transofrmations to write the following goniometric equations in the form $F(x)=c$, where $F$ is sin, cos, tan or cot.

1. $\cos (x)=3\sin (x)$
2. $\sin (2x)=0.3$
3. $2\sin (2x)-\cos(2x)=0$
4. $\tan (5^{\circ}-x)=0$

I have done the following:

1. $\cos (x)=3\sin (x) \Rightarrow \frac{\cos (x)}{\sin (x)}=3 \Rightarrow \cot (x)=3$, so $F=\cot$.
2. $\sin (2x)=0.3 \Rightarrow 2\sin (x)\cos (x)=0.3 \Rightarrow \sin (x)\cos (x)=0.15 \Rightarrow \sin^2 (x)\cos^2 (x)=0.0225$ $ \\ \Rightarrow (1-\cos^2(x))\cos^2 (x)=0.0225\Rightarrow \cos^2 (x)-\cos^4 (x)=0.0225$.

   Do we solve now $u^2-u^4=0.0225$ and then we get equations in the form $\cos^2(x)=u \Rightarrow \cos(x)=\pm \sqrt{u}$ ?
3. $2\sin (2x)-\cos(2x)=0 \Rightarrow 2\sin (2x)=\cos(2x) \Rightarrow \frac{\sin (2x)}{\cos(2x)}=2 \Rightarrow \tan (2x)=2 \Rightarrow \frac{2\tan (x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}=2$ $ \\ \Rightarrow 2\tan (x)=2(1-\tan^2(x))$ and we continue similarily to 2 ?
4. $\tan (5^{\circ}-x)=0$ do we apply here the addition theorem?

(b) Why can we not solve the equation $\sin (x)+\cos (2x)=1$ graphically?

Comment: $2\sin (2x) = \cos (2x)$ means that $\tan 2x = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Ah yes, you're right!! Is my approach at each equation correct? @Forester

Comment: According to me, it's correct. By addition theorem fo you mean to use $\tan (A-B) = \frac{ \tan A -  \tan B}{1+ \tan A \tan B}$?

Comment: Yes! Or does this formula not help us in this case?@Forester

Comment: It helps..........

Comment: Ok, great!! Do you have also an idea about (b) ? @Forester

Comment: Not a very clear idea but I know that plotting the graph of sin x + cos 2x can be difficult by hand and also one of the roots is irrational. Here is the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kpcjw25vuu  .   One trivial solution is x=0

Comment: Is this difficult because one argument is $x$ and the other one is $2x$ ? Or because we have a sum of trigonometric functions? @Forester

Comment: Both factors contribute but I think more because of the different arguments. sin x + cos x does not have a very difficult graph(https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kpcjw25vuu)  The different arguments result in different local maximas and amplitude

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @Forester

Comment: The solution for (2) will give you two values for $u$, so four values for $\pm\sqrt u$. However because you squared the equation along the way, two of those values are false solutions you introduced. You'll have to identify which two of the solutions are correct. But you will have to get creative to convert those remaining two solutions into a single equation of the form desired.